# How to prevent users from installing new Chrome extensions

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, operating-systems, google-chrome-extensions

I am trying to prevent users from installing new extensions on Chrome. I have tried the registry method outlined in [this](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/prevent-users-from-installing-extensions-in-google-chrome) website, but the problem I am having is that it deletes previous extensions, which I would like to prevent. I have tried searching for other answers, but they almost all outline a method for preventing all installations.

Is there a way to block only new extension installations and keep old ones?

Thank you.

Comment: "Is there a way to block only new extension installations and keep old ones?" - Yes; You have to use the appropriate group policies to only allow specific extensions. *You would need to spherically allow the 'old" extensions.*

Comment: Does [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7532015?hl=en) help?

Comment: Your own link tells you exactly what to do : block all extensions but allow the ones already installed.

Comment: If you have access to the underlying filesystem where Chrome userdata is stored, setting a deny permission for creation of new files in <UserData>\Extensions\ may be faster than messing with Group Policy